# Shell command to list all files in a directory

Tags: bash, shell

Does anyone know a shell command that could list all of the files in a directory, only showing those that I own, it should be in bash as well.

Comment: The short answer is `ls` is the list command. Typing `man ls` will bring up the manual page for it. To list all it's `ls -a`. To list all with a long-listing it's `ls -al`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : Perhaps `ls -Al` would be more useful here. But in both cases, also files with different owners would be listed. Also, it is not clear from the question, whether the OP wants to see only files, or other directory entries (subdirectories, symlinks) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can find files owned by the current user ($USER) in combination with the `find` command with the `-user` parameter.

```
find . -type f -user $USER | xargs ls -l
```